# Is that possible to know when some user is deleting some app in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, logout

I am on a situation, when some user is deleting some app, I need to send a Logout signal to the server from that Specific account, that mean any other user can not see recently deleted app's user to any other opened app. Is there any way to do this?

I have tried a continuous checking using background fetch on the server that some user is updating their status or not, if not updated for 5 min then I am forcefully logging out that user. But for that I can not understand, the user is in Background or user Deleted the app. So anyone has any idea to recover from that situation?

Comment: I think the APNS feedback service may help. The service will add those device tokens that the app is not installed in the device to a list. And when you query it, it will return you the list of device token. If you have maintain all the user's device token, you may consider those users have uninstalled the app. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Appendixes/BinaryProviderAPI.html

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is absolutely no reliable way to know when an user remove your application from his device.